# 2090. K Radius Subarray Averages Leetcode

Tags: java, arrays, loops, pointers

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [2090. K Radius Subarray Averages](https://leetcode.com/problems/k-radius-subarray-averages/description/):

> You are given a **0-indexed** array `nums` of `n` integers, and an integer `k`.
>
> The **k-radius average** for a subarray of `nums` **centered** at some index `i` with the **radius** `k` is the average of **all** elements in `nums` between the indices `i - k` and `i + k` (**inclusive**). If there are less than `k` elements before or after the index `i`, then the **k-radius average** is -1.
>
> Build and return *an array* `avgs` *of length* `n` *where* `avgs[i]` *is the **k-radius average** for the subarray centered at index* `i`.
>
> The average of `x` elements is the sum of the `x` elements divided by `x`, using **integer division**. The integer division truncates toward zero, which means losing its fractional part.
>
> For example, the average of four elements 2, 3, 1, and 5 is (2 + 3 + 1 + 5) / 4 = 11 / 4 = 2.75, which truncates to 2.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - `n == nums.length`
> - `1 <= n <= 105`
> - `0 <= nums[i], k <= 105`

I have tried out this code, but apparently it fails for only one test case and not any other one. The test case being too large, I can't even figure out my error.

What is my mistake?

My code:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] getAverages(int[] nums, int k) {
        int[] avg= new int[nums.length];
        for(int i=0; i < nums.length; i++){
            if(i<k || (int)nums.length-i<=k){
                avg[i]=-1;
            }
            else{
                int temp=nums[i];
                for(int j=1; j<=k; j++){
                    temp=temp+nums[i-j]+ nums[i+j];
                    //System.out.println(temp);
                }
                avg[i]= temp/(2*k+1);
            }
        }
        return avg;
    }
}
```

The last test case consisted of `k=4000`, and the input array consisted of many repeated 10000.

Comment: Don't recompute the sum for every element.  Once you have computed 2+3+4+5+6, you can compute the next one by adding 7 and subtracting 2.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `temp` as an `int` will not work for larger test cases, because it is given that  and `nums[i]` can be as large as 10<sup>5</sup> and so the sums you have to calculate can be as large as 2⋅10<sup>10</sup> which is out of range for an `int`, resulting on wrong results. Use `long` instead. Then when you divide it into an average, cast to `int`.

Secondly, your algorithm has a nested loop that gives it a time complexity of O(), while this can be done with O() time complexity if you keep track of the sum (`temp`) incrementally: As you move forward, you can use the previous value of `temp` and subtract the left most value that drops out of the "window", and add the new value that enters that window on the right side.

Spoiler solution:

> `class Solution {
>      public int[] getAverages(int[] nums, int k) {
>          int[] avg = new int[nums.length];
>          Arrays.fill(avg, -1);
>          int width = k + k + 1;
>          if (width <= nums.length) {
>              long sum = 0;
>              for (int i = width - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
>                  sum += nums[i];
>              }
>              for (int i = width - 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
>                  sum += nums[i];
>                  avg[i - k] = (int) (sum / width);
>                  sum -= nums[i + 1 - width];
>              }
>          }
>          return avg;
>      }
>  }`